# How to get count related Lookup value programmatically?

Tags: 2010, development, lookup-column

Another day, another question ;)

So, I have two custom Lists, "Attendees" and "Events". In the Events-List there's a Lookupfield "Registrations" which I want to fill programmatically on page_load. In the Events List there's a Lookupfield "Event".

First of all: I know this can be done via UI of SharePoint, and to be honest I just implemented it like this at the moment. But what I really want to achieve is the following:

In the Events-List there are two more columns, lets call them "minimal attendees" and "maximal attendees".

So now I don't just want to show the number in the "Registrations"-Column for an event, I want to show it like this: "1 of 15", ideally via SPHttpEncode in different colors (something like "orange" if registrations < min. Attendees, green if >= min. attendees and < max. attendees and red if registrations == count_related)

Now I don't know how to get the count-related value programmatically (using c#) and hope you could help :)

Best regards,
Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you use SPLookupField which multiple property is set to true. In this case you can cast field value to the [SPFieldLookupValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvaluecollection.aspx) and get its Count.

```
string rawvalue = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Predecessors].ToString();
SPFieldLookupValueCollection values = new SPFieldLookupValueCollection(rawvalue);
int c = values.Count;
```

Comment: Hi Alexander and first of all thank you for your answer. To be honest, this seems to be a "bad hack" in my opinion, but I haven't found any other way yet. I'm still searching for one, though. If I won't find one the next 24h or so, I'll check your answer for it is "a" answer, I just think there have to be better ways to achieve my goal.

Comment: @Dominik, you can also look at remark for [CountRelated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookup.countrelated.aspx) property of lookup field.

Comment: I did it via `int registrations = Convert.ToInt32(currEventItem["Registrations"].ToString()` now ("Registrations" is the count-related lookup). It is a mess, in my opinion, but apart from the view-issue I need the int value to check if the registration limit has been reached, so... just works ;) Nonetheless you are right with your answer, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is an old Topic. But a great one for my Problem!

I want to integrate the value of a look up field (Count related) into a button.
What I fail to do is the Integration in the button code.

Does anybody know the solution?

Here the code for the Button:

```
="<input id=ViewButton onclick=""javascript:OpenPopUpPage('http://part_one_of_the_link"&Filter_by_Column&"&part_two_of_the_link');"" type=button value=""show lookup value (Count related)""/>"
```

if anybody has an idea - would be great!!