# Use count-related column value as int in a SP Designer-workflow

Tags: 2010, development, workflow, lookup-column, designer-workflow

I have another problem concerning the count-related column-value of SP2010 in a workflow(see also: [How to get count related Lookup value programmatically?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53446/how-to-get-count-related-lookup-value-programmatically) ).

my use-case: I have a column "actual attendees" in a custom list named "Events". It is a count-related lookup-column for another lookup-column in a list called "attendees". 
Now I want to check this column in a workflow like this:

```
if (actual attendees > minimal attendees)
do this
else if (actual attendees <= ...)
do that
```

The Problem: As mentioned in the referenced thread, the calculated column-value returns a string-value (btw: I think this is a weird concept, Microsoft. Grrr.). Programmatically I solved this misconception by using `Convert.ToInt32...`, but I do sort of "wait for date, then check attendee number, then send e-mail" in my workflow, So I think I can't use a programmatical solution without doing lots of code (or to be short: I need a workflow for this, do I?)

Now in a SP Designer workflow, sadly this conversion seems to be not possible for me. I tried

```
//Attendees is a Number-Variable, tried with string, too, but not working too.
Set Variable:Attendees to Current_Item:actual Attendees
```

but when instantiating the workflow I get the error (using german version here, so I try my best to translate it):

> Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type.

I'm out of ideas for this and I hope someone could help me out.

Best regards,
Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it was my fault. I'd set the return type of the count-related lookup-value to `Lookupvalue (as Number)` (translated, using german version here). It works if you'll use 'double' as return value for the count-related returnvalue. Just seemed logical to me to use the other one, but... hey, works! ;)

Greetings and sorry for taking your time.